# How to list custom taxonomy categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type (CPT) which contains products, and a taxonomy that contains product terms. I need to display these terms on the page 'Products' and when clicked on a certain term, it needs to display the products which belong to the term.

By the way, when I click 'view' on a certain term, it only displays one product's title. I created the CPT and taxonomy using the CPT UI plugin.

Here is my page-products.php template file code (which lists all the products) :

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Products
*/
?>

 <?php get_header('header.php') ?>

 <!--Opening container or wrap outside of the loop-->
 <div class="container my-container">
 <!--start the loop-->
   <?php
   $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$the_query = null;
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

$i = 0;
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

if($i % 3 == 0) { ?>

<div class="row">

<?php
}
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="my-inner">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div>
</div>

  <?php $i++;
  if($i != 0 && $i % 3 == 0) { ?>
    </div><!--/.row-->
    <div class="clearfix">fgfd</div>

  <?php
   } ?>

  <?php
    endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: This happens automatically if you use the main query in the correct templates. Review the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to see the required templates. Post type/taxonomy archives do not need to be, and should not be, implemented as page templates.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I should query the taxonomy terms in my page-products.php first right?

Comment: No. There shouldn’t be any page templates or secondary queries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a list of your custom taxonomies, you can use the [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function to create a loop:

```
// Get the taxonomy's terms
$terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'your-taxonomy',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </a><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Though I have another problem - once I click on my category, only one post title shows up. Is there a specific template I need to have which displays posts by category? Sorry if I sound stupid, but I'm lost.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not stupid at all. This might have several reasons. One could be that you set the post per page to 1 in your _"Reading"_ settings in the dashboard. Other issue might be with the template. Try checking the `taxonomy-your_taxonomy.php` or `taxonomy.php` if it exists. You might also have a `pre_get_posts` filter in your `functions.php` file, limiting the results.

Comment: Okay, creating the taxonomy template worked, once I press on the category, I get a list of my posts. But using the code in my original post , I get the same products no matter which category I click on. For example, I have a category with 3 products and when I click it I see these products, but I see the same products when I click a different category. I think I need to use the category ID right?

Comment: Yes of course. You need to do a `tax_query` if you are planning to use your own code. Take a look into [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class and feel free to ask a new question if the problem persists.

Comment: Hey Jack. I really want to thank you for all the help. I was able to get the end result I wanted. Cheers to you man! :)

Comment: how to get category taxonomy