# How to show category list in WordPress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, categories

If anyone know, if there's plugin to customize taxonomy list it will be faster to do.
But here's my question.

i create post type **"product"** and the categories.
inside post type **product**, i make categories like this

- Book

  - Novel
  - Dictionary

    - English
    - Korean
- Gadget

  - Phone
  - Tablet

So, in the page
i want to list *sub-category* inside **Book**,
the result = Novel and Dictionary.
And when i click on Dictionary for example, it will show me
list of **Dictionary** *sub-category*,
the result = English and Korean.

Then for last, when i click on English
page will show all post items inside English category.

Comment: This should help: [How to list custom taxonomy categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287501/how-to-list-custom-taxonomy-categories)

Comment: i try to list, but when i put the code it show me all list of categories.  
what i mean is, when i'm on Book category page, the page will showing Novel and dictionary only.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the results to the children of the current product category, you can use `parent` parameter in [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms). The `id` of the current category, to be set as the `parent` value, will be get using [get_queried_object()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

```
$term_id = 0;
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
//
// check if it's a custom category
if ( $queried_object instanceof WP_Term )
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'parent'     => $term_id,  // get only direct children
    //'child_of' => $term_id,  // get all children 
    //'hide_empty' => false,
);
$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

If you would like to attach the current category to the results (before the child categories):

```
$terms = get_terms( $args );
if ($queried_object instanceof WP_Term) {
    array_unshift( $terms, $queried_object );
}
```

---

An example of the code in its entirety:

```
if ( is_archive('product') ) //  OR: is_product_category()
{
    $term_id = 0;
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    //
    // check if it's a custom category
    if ( $queried_object instanceof WP_Term )
        $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'parent'     => $term_id,  // get only direct children
        //'child_of' => $term_id,  // get all children 
        //'hide_empty' => false,
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $args );
    //
    // add current category at beginning
    if ($queried_object instanceof WP_Term) {
        array_unshift( $terms, $queried_object );
    }
    //
    // Check if any term exists and print them all
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) 
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
            printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
                esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ),
                $term->name
            );
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'your-category-name',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'title_li'     => '',
  'hide_empty'   => false
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

You can use the wp_list_categories function also for taxonomies.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

I found this, to be more specific i put parent category id for it.
and maybe i will make the result as shortcode.

```
$term_id = 3;
$taxonomy_name = 'category_name';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```